# Is it semantically correct to not include .js filetype in <script> reference?

Tags: javascript, html

I have inherited some code that links to JavaScript files as follows:

```
<script src="/js/scriptfile" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

where I was expecting:

```
<script src="/js/scriptfile.js"></script>
```

I understand that including `type="text/javascript"` is optional in HTML5, but what about filetype?

Note: the JavaScript files are actually loading and operating as intended.  The "[Marked as Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736551/is-it-semantically-correct-to-not-include-js-filetype-in-script-reference)" answer is specific to the `type` attribute, where my question directly relates to the requirement for a file extension on a file.

Comment: What does the specification say? You did read the specification right? Otherwise this is just you asking someone to read it and tell you what it says.

Comment: type= is for inline ( same file ) script, could be javascript, VB ot Tck. src is for external script ( different file) give file address eg. `  type='myscript.js'  `

Comment: @Arif Burhan I think you want to say src="myscript.js"?

Comment: Note: my question is not specifically related to the type attribute, but instead is it necessary to include a filetype (ie - .js) when linking to a script file?

Comment: Doesn't have to be `.js` .... as long as url resolves correctly and server sends it as text

Comment: @PVL within tags you can use either single or double quotes, as long as you have the same at both ends, this is to allow the other type to be in the string, eg.  name="O'Brien"

Comment: Note that it's not uncommon to have  a programming language that compiles multiple script files into one and does minification. Probably not as common as it used to be due to better development build tools but likely still lots of it out there

Comment: @Arif Burham yes I know i was talking about where you said type="myscript.js" instead of src="myscript.js".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML"5" thinks that you will use javascript. If you use another file type instead of js then you should mention it.